# python runtime version statistics

Tags: python

Is there any breakdown of how many devices have python 2.6, 2.7, 3.*?

I'm spoiled by OS install statistics, like [Android's](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). Of course, the collection methods used there aren't available to Python. For Java, I found [this](https://plumbr.eu/blog/java/java-version-and-vendor-data-analyzed-2016-edition), which certainly isn't official, and the methodology leaves a lot to be desired, but that's the kind of thing I'm interested in.

Answer (score 2):

There was a survey in 2014 on usage statistics, mostly on 2.x vs 3.x. But not including platforms/devices.

[The python usage survey](http://www.randalolson.com/2015/01/30/python-usage-survey-2014/) includes a more thorough breakdown:
[image: python usage survey graph]

The website credited with the underlying data is [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150228101023/http://blog.frite-camembert.net:80/python-survey-2014.html).

And there is always google trends, which obviously is not a usage breakdown but rather a more general account of how popular search terms are. It would allow for search terms such as "python android" and "python iOS".
See [here](https://www.google.co.uk/trends/explore?date=today%2012-m&q=python%202,python%203,python%202.7):
[image: google trends python comparison]

I think checking distributions such as Anaconda would be a way of approximating python version and OSs. Unfortunately, the Anaconda website does not include a number-of-downloads tracker that is rather common. 
Another approximation would be the number of commits for Spyder releases on [GitHub](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases).